# Using custom authlogic error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I am using the authlogic gem for user validation on one of my sites. All is going well, but I am wondering if it's possible to change the error message that gets returned when the user types in an invalid email address.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can override the settings for email validation with `validates_format_of_email_field_options`. However, if you only want to change the message you can merge options with `merge_validates_format_of_email_field_options` so that only the options you specify are overridden. You specify settings in your User controller like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_authentic do |c|
        c.merge_validates_format_of_email_field_options :message => 'My message'
    end
end
```

You can also change the settings for length and uniqueness validations. There are also a lot more other settings, take a look at the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/projects/binarylogic/authlogic), in the ::Config sections of each module you can find settings and their default values and how to override them.

Alternatively you can use localization and set `error_messages.email_invalid` (that's what the plugin looks for before setting it to the default English sentence, also useful if you are building an international application).

Answer (score 16):

authlogic has a special setting for this purpose:

```
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base  
  generalize_credentials_error_messages true
end
```

The error message will be the same: *"Email/Password combination is not valid"*, whether the password or email is bad.  You can change the text of the message specifying a string instead of `true`:

```
generalize_credentials_error_messages "Try again"
```

Comment: thank you for adding this. not alot of places mention how to handle credential errors on logon.

Answer (score 4):

Override Authlogic error messages by changing in en.yml file
It works for me.

```
en:
  authlogic:
      error_messages:
         login_blank: "Please enter the email address."
         login_not_found: "This email address is already in the system. Please choose a different email address."
         login_invalid: "Please enter a valid email address."
```